# Using UIScreen.main.bounds to get screen size on Mac OS

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have an app with some graphics that I've written for iOS and Mac OSX.   I need to find out the size of the display in pixels in order to set the proportions of the graphics.   On iOS, UIScreen.main.bounds works fine, but when I run it on the Mac version, the width of the screen returns as 960 pixels when it is actually 2880 pixels.   Interestingly, when I use UIDevice to query the system info

```
   let d = UIDevice()
   print (d.model)
   print (d.name)
   print (d.systemVersion)
   print (d.systemName)
```

the output is:

```
iPad
My MacBook Pro
10.15.6
Mac OS X
```

Why is the model an iPad?

If I do the following inline code

```
class TestClass
{
    #if os(watchOS)
        static var device = 0
    #elseif os(iOS)
        static var device = 1
    #elseif os(macOS)
        static var device = 2
    #endif
}
```

and call

```
print (TestClass.device)
```

if returns a 1 -- i.e., it thinks it's iOS.

Again, I am not using the simulator -- I am running the app as "My Mac".   Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `nativeBounds`

Comment: Another option is to multiply the width by the screen scale

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus    My MacBook is 2880 x 1800.   When I called UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.width, it returned 1920.   UIScreen.main.scale = 2.0, and 2.0 * 960 = 1920.   So, unless I'm doing something wrong, the numbers are still not quite adding up.

Comment: It probably detects the size of the window which is the same size as the iPad screen in landscape.